# How to import a function from a .js file when using Typescript and Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue.js project that is using Typescript and it is working well but I have an old piece of javascript with a lot of logic in it that I need to use and I would like to import it but I seem to have tried every combination of Import syntax to the .vue file and am unable to load the javascript.

I've tried

```js
import * as revpubeditor  from '../modules/revpubeditor'
import revpubeditor  from '../modules/revpubeditor'
import { revpubeditor } from '../modules/revpubeditor'
```

and have also altered the .js file and added a .d.ts file so that it will compile and not give any errors but at runtime in the browser the revpubeditor that I have imported is not found by webpack.

How should this be setup and consumed?  I am not worried about it being strongly typed I just want the webpack loader to find the module.

Comment: How about `const revpubeditor = require('../modules/revpubeditor')`? I've had to do that in TypeScript projects before for JS libraries that don't export a module

Comment: Can you share minimal code snippet for `revpubeditor.vue` file?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I need to do the same and it would be useful to know how.